# how to have an active display but keyboard locked

Tags: macbook-pro

I have found much information about locking screens on MAC's but what I cant find is how to have the display continue to show whatever is on it, but to have the keyboard locked and require a password to allow the computer to be actively used, not just as a display.
This is so I can have a live status screen displayed but the laptop cant be messed with without 'unlocking'
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks...
Stewie

Answer (score 1):

There's a program for this called [Lockey](http://www.getlockey.com/)

I have not tested this, nor I own this. But you could try it out. 
It's not free (at this moment) and they do not support Mavericks (yet) as they claim OS X 10.5 up to 10.8